How to filter and select the row based on the highest value of the two cells in Snowflake?
I have the following two tables

Packed Cases:



Outbound Cases:


I am using the following query in Snowflake to join the tables:
SELECT 
    Packed_Cases.Box_no,
    Packed_Cases.Item_Style,
    Packed_Cases.Qty.,
    Outbound_Cases.Box_no,
    Outbound_Cases.Store,
    MAX_BY(Outbound_Cases.Date_Modified,Outbound_Cases.Date_Modified) AS Date_Modified,
    Outbound_Cases.SYS_State
FROM 
    Packed_Cases 
LEFT JOIN 
    Outbound_Cases ON Packed_Cases.Box_no = Outbound_Cases.Box_no
WHERE 
    Outbound_Cases.Store LIKE '%15%' AND
    Outbound_Cases.SYS_State = '50'
GROUP BY 
    Packed_Cases.Box_no, Packed_Cases.Item_Style, Packed_Cases.Qty.,
    Outbound_Cases.Box_no, Outbound_Cases.Store, Outbound_Cases.SYS_State

After running the query I am getting the following output which has duplicate lines highlighted in yellow. I am using the MAX_BY function on Outbound_Cases.Date_Modified to filter the similar rows and pick the row with latest date with matching Box_no to Packed_cases table.

I am expecting the following output where the Box_no from the Packed_cases table will pull the store number, date modified and Sys_state from Outbound_Cases table with latest date modified.


Please do not use images as input and output, instead use text based format in markdown for the input and output.Please use mock data instead of real data.

Thank you for the recommendation. This is not the real data. I have created a sample data based on real data. The box no and dates are randomly generated. It is used to represent and explain the actual data format.

I have first picked the latest row for box_no based on latest date_modified date, you can test and let me know if it works, I was unable to run the query as the sample input data is not in text format in the question.
Here is the sample query
with latest_outbound_cases as (
    select 
        box_no,
        store,
        max(date_modified) as latest_date_modified,  
        sys_state
    from outbound_cases
    where store like '%15%'   
      and sys_state = '50'    
    group by box_no, store, sys_state
)
    
select 
    packed_cases.box_no,
    packed_cases.item_style,
    packed_cases.qty,
    latest_outbound_cases.store,
    latest_outbound_cases.latest_date_modified as date_modified,  
    latest_outbound_cases.sys_state
from packed_cases
left join latest_outbound_cases 
    on packed_cases.box_no = latest_outbound_cases.box_no;


Thank you Samhita, the Query worked perfectly after making few modification related to my data set. Also, for future, I will keep in mind to put the data sample data in text format. Appreciate all your help!

Thank you @RK03 for letting me know! Glad you found it helpful! :)
